# Как брать определенные эелементы, без их имен,классов и тп

Tags: c#, html, anglesharp

Вроде это можно взять спомощью css, но как-то не получается

html

```
     <ul>
  <li> · <a href="/index.php?a=index&id=125" style="color:" >Car</a></li>
<li> · <a href="/index.php?a=index&id=26" style="color:" >dresses</a></li>
<li> · <a href="/index.php?id=25" style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0)" >Shoes</a></li>
<li> · <a href="/index.php?id=23" style="color:" >Busted</a></li>
<li> · <a href="/index.php?a=index&id=24" style="color:" >Motocross</a></li>                                                    
</ul>
```

и таких куча li, я думаю, может можно как-то по style значению искать

```
 var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithJs();
            var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
            //description item_table-description
            //Just get the DOM representation
            Console.WriteLine(allhtml);
            IDocument document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(allhtml));
            var all_web = document.QuerySelectorAll("ul > li:hover");
 foreach (var el_web in all_web)
{
Console.WriteLine(el_web.TextContent);
}
```

У меня берутся все li, но мне нужны определенные

Comment: Вот вы смотрите на это все и что конкретно вы хотите взять? Какие критерии поиска? Вот отыщите эти уникальные критерии и задайте их в парсере. Например тут уникальны имена, уникальны id в url, цвет (стиль), если он такой приходит с сервера, то он вам не поможет. Может не знаю, у вас нужный элемент всегда сидит на 3-м месте, можете по этому критерию забрать элемент. Короче, вам нужно нечто уникальное, что выберет этот объект из кучи других.

Comment: Суть в том, что я не могу взять по именам и по ссылку, я их грубо говоря незнаю. Суть задачи взять подобные элементы, и пройтись в foreach и брать значения. Там на сайте куча li, половина не нужна. Нужные мне элеметы одинаковы только в css `style="vertical-align: inherit;"` - в этом они одинаков(это внутри li). Получается нужно как-то указть это, что бери эелементы с таким то css, но как?

Comment: `.Where(x=>x.GetAttribute("style") == "ваши значения")`?

Comment: Пробовал как в примере `color:` не помогло, он не находит, просто пропускат и все, даже ошибку не выбрасывает

Comment: Попробуйте тогда не `= "Ваше значение"`, а `.Contains("Значение")`.

Comment: Все равно не берети пропускает, пробовал и так `document.QuerySelector("ul").Children.Where(m => m.LocalName == "li");` тоже без результатно

Comment: Может можно взять эелемент, в котором есть эти li, у меня есть эелемент с div.fl, в нем li эти есть но без классов и названий, я пробовал так делать `document.QuerySelector("div.fl").QuertySelectorAll("li")` но тоже без результатно. Может я не то делаю, есть дугой способ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Я нашел за что зацепиться,но мне возвращает null, если не сложно, подскажите что не так делаю. `var container = document.QuerySelector<IHtmlAnchorElement>("div#js-scroll.tb-item");
                        var matches = container.QuerySelectorAll<IHtmlAnchorElement>("li").Where(x=>x.ClassName!=null && x.ClassName.Equals("fl"));
                        `Пробовал вместо equals, contains ставить, результат тот же. Имя класса у li, fl. li с классаи fl куча, а тут все в div#js-scroll.tb-item, в этом div есть ul, а в ul уже li идет, почему null возвращает, Как взять?

Comment: Убрал `IHtmlAnchorElement` в container, теперь ошибки не вылетают, просто он ничего не видет, и пропускает цикл, если убираю и matches, то он делает цикл, но информацию не дает, хотя я указываю в цикле .getAttribute('href')

Comment: Понизил версию AngleSharp до 13.0 заработало